# Database-free token based (Oauth2 like) API Authentification, is that safe?

Tags: node.js, http, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I've been reading a lot recently about how to secure a REST API properly and am still not sure I'm doing the right design choice.

I have an API exposed by a Nodejs Web Server. Events are organized (basically people can answer questions), thus users can use the API if they possess a specific code that they type through a client-side interface to authenticate themselves.

There might be thousands of users authenticated for one event and thousands of events running at the same time, using the same API. Therefore I would like to not store any session information on the server side.

My identification flow is the following

- Client sends the event-specific code to the /login service of the API.
- Webserver checks the code, retrieves the corresponding event, and generates a token that encapsulates the event ID (that user is participating to), an timestamp-based generated userID and the expiration date of the stateless session -> this results in a encrypted token containing a small payload. (using SH256 and a secret hardcoded on the server) and is sent back to the client
- Token is stored on the client side for future API calls.
- User starts answering questions, using the Token in the Authorization http header
- Server checks the token using nodejs module passport-http-token, and decrypts the user ID, event ID and checks the expiration date. It saves the user's answer along with the userID.

So basically no session store, although I had the feeling that in most of the OAuth2 solutions I found, people were storing tokens in a server-side database.

Assuming that the first API call to /login (that sends the event code) is secured using https, what are the flaws ? Can the SH 256 token be reverse engineered ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think your approach is OK. People don't always store tokens, Json Web Tokens (JWT) are usually used without DB. For checking token validity, it is enough to use tokens with signatures (JWS). Do you need to hide token details? If not, no encryption is needed at all and you're still safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What does JWS add in comparison to JWT ? (Is it a client-side signature?) What do you mean by "hiding token details" ?

Comment: It adds a server-side signature to the token to prove that token contents are not tampered with by a client. However, contrary to encryption it does not hide token contents from the world. As a result, e.g. a protected resource can interpret token contents and validate the token on its own without consulting the server.